# Why does "wsl" produce different results when using quotes?

Tags: windows, windows-10, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Why does the `wsl` command produce different results when the linux command is wrapped in quotes?

```
C:\Users\elitebook>wsl "ls /"
/bin/bash: ls /: No such file or directory

C:\Users\elitebook>wsl ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  init  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

I'm confused by this result. Moreover, how can I run commands that are less trivial, e.g. suppose I want to run `echo $PATH > /home/out.file`:

```
C:\Users\arman_ogda7cp>wsl echo $PATH > /home/out.file
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a CMD prompt, the WSL command reads what is after `WSL` as-is. You'd get the same from `"ls /"` (with the quotes) in any bash shell. It's a bash thing. As Hannu says, it's looking for an executable file called `ls /` which, in any case, is not allowed, because you can't have a file with a slash in its name. If you want, from a Windows CMD prompt, to see the result of making WSL carry out `ls /` then type `WSL ls /` with no quotes.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.592]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Mike>WSL ls /  
acct  boot   data  etc   init  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
bin   cache  dev   home  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var

C:\Users\Mike>
```

If you want to use special characters, e.g. pipe, redirection, etc, remember that the CMD shell will interpret these, unless they are escaped. To pass them to the WSL shell, escape them in the CMD way, with a caret (^):

<sub>wsl echo $PATH ^> ~/mypath.txt

    wsl cat ~/.bashrc ^| grep sudo ^> ~/test.txt

    wsl cd ~; ls ~/*.BAD ^> /dev/null 2^&^>1 ^|^| echo no .BAD files in $PWD ^&^& echo found one or more .BAD files in $PWD</sub>

Comment: In that case how do I escape special characters when running more complex commands?

Comment: see edited answer.

Comment: `wsl echo $PATH ^>^> ~/mypath.txt` does not appear to append.  Known bug I wish they would fix:  https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4400

Answer (score 2):

***NOTE: I have NO access to wsl***

Plausible cause:

> wsl fails to handle arguments in a sane manner.

Try this:
First launch `wsl bash --login`,
then at the bash prompt:
`echo $PATH > $HOME/out.file`
`cat $HOME/out-file`

Note:
/home - is the folder that contains folders for user's homes.
So for any logged in $user there is a folder named /home/$user/

`wsl ls /` # look for the ls command and provide `/` as argument.
`wsl "ls /"` # look for an executable named exactly `ls /`, no arguments.
The last similar to:
`wsl "ls -l"` # look for an executable named exactly `ls -l`, no arguments.